# JPA Find method returns wrongly associated objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I persist a list of objects A having a List of objects B.

I persist 2 objects A, both having a list of 3 objects B. The 3 objects are the same in both lists (same reference).

In the DB, the association seems fine :

```
Table A_2_B
ID_B        | ID_A
--------------------------
B1          | A1
B2          | A1
B3          | A1
B1          | A2
B2          | A2
B3          | A2
```

When retrieving the list of objects A, instead of having a list of size 2 with my 2 objects A, both having a list of 3 objects B, I get a list of 6 objects A all having a list of these 3 objects B.
In the DB, it seems that the mapping is done correctly but not when retreiving my objects.

What is not done correctly ?

Here under is the mapping file for the A objects:

```
<entity name="ProductDefinition" class="mapp3.model.A" access="FIELD">

    <table name="T_A"/>

    <attributes>

      <id name="uniqueIdentifier">
        <column name="UUID" length="100"/>
      </id>

      <basic name="type">
        <column name="TYPE" length="100" />
      </basic>

      <many-to-many name="B" target-entity="mapp3.model.B" fetch="EAGER" access="FIELD">

        <join-table name="A_2_B"/>

        <cascade>
          <cascade-persist/>
          <cascade-merge/>
          <cascade-refresh/>
        </cascade>

      </many-to-many>

    </attributes>
```

update, mapping between entity and A :

```
<entity name="Universe" class="mapp3.model.Entity" access="FIELD">

        <table name="ENTITY"/>
        <attributes>

            <id name="uri">
                <column name="URI" length="200"/>
            </id>

           <one-to-many name="A" target-entity="mapp3.model.A" fetch="EAGER" access="FIELD">

                <join-table name="ENTITY_2_A"/>

                <cascade>
                    <cascade-persist/>
                    <cascade-merge/>
                    <cascade-refresh/>
                </cascade>

            </one-to-many>

        </attributes>

    </entity>
```

Comment: Show the query you are using for JPA to bring in the entities.  Because you have an eager join on the mapping, your provider is likely generating SQL that does a cartesian join between the tables, as there will be 6 rows returned for these 2x3 objects, but it should filter the results when building the entity unless you have asked for the join in the query itself.  If you have, you can use the Distinct key word to filter duplicate As from the results.

Comment: I'm doing a simple find using the entity manager..

Comment: A simple find returns a single entity, not a collection.

Comment: Ok, but I have an entity containing a collection of A :)

Comment: Ok, then it isn't a find operation that is messing up, it is your mapping from that Entity to A.  How are you fetching that entity, how have you set up the mappings between it and A, and how are you adding references?

Comment: thanks for you help. I added the mapping file between Entity and A. It's pretty simple and I cannot see where something could go wrong.

Comment: Assuming it isn't an issue with your population of the Universe instance's A collection, it looks like a Hibernate issue with using eager relationships.  Changing the relationships to Lazy would help or using @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT).  Something similar is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795921/hibernate-getting-too-many-rows

Comment: yes thanks, I changed to lazy and it now works better !